# BaseExpandableListAdapter getChildView update TextView per item

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an expandable list view that I am populating with values from a Track object that contains a list of Locations. It runs well. However my TextView.setText is filling in each textView with the LAST value in the list of Locations.

How can I fix this?

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child_item_layout, null);

            for (Location loc : trackList.get(groupPosition).getLocations()) {
                //Log.i(MY_EXPANDABLELIST_ACTIVITY_TAG, "Location X: " + loc.getLongitude());

                TextView textLongitude = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_longitude);
                textLongitude.setText("Longitude: " + Double.toString(loc.getLongitude()));

                TextView textLatitude = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_latitude);
                textLatitude.setText("Latitude: " + Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()));

                TextView textAltitude = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_altitude);
                textAltitude.setText("Altitude: " + Double.toString(loc.getAltitude()));

                TextView textSpeed = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_speed);
                textSpeed.setText("Speed: " + Float.toString(loc.getSpeed()));

                TextView textAccuracy = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_accuracy);
                textAccuracy.setText("Accuracy: " + Float.toString(loc.getAccuracy()));

                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
                Date date = new Date(loc.getTime());
                String formattedDate = format.format(date);
                TextView textTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_time);
                textTime.setText("Time: " + formattedDate);
            }               
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

The values are correct in LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I think it's because with this method you re copying the pointer to your object loc, even thought you're in a loop the value will be the same,
I fixed it by making a new instantiation of my object in your case loc

(ex loc = new loc

loc = tracklist.get(i) ) something like that